Does bazel support order only build dependencies?
I am new to bazel.  The last big/massive build project I was involved with was based on gmake and that was a while back.  When I left that project we were considering gmake's order only dependencies (OOD) as a general design solution.  However, I can't find much (if anything?) in bazel regarding support for OOD.  SCons appears to have picked up support for OOD  some time ago.
The question is, does bazel support order-only dependencies (OOD) similar to what is found in gmake?
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html
The above link references the creation of directories as an example, but the use case of interest is not that but is in fact building a large bazel project without developer centric manual management of all the fine-grain build DAG dependencies (edges).  For example, I would like to use both the native toolchain (gcc -MMD for the C/C++ code) and third party scanners for the other languages/components of the build (similar to SCons or whatever) to create and manage the fine grain DAG edges automatically.  The fine-grain edges are needed for accurate and fast incremental builds.
Consider the following gmake OOD snippet:
# syntax
# targets : normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites

$(ALL_COMPILED_C_FILES):| $(ALL_GEN_C_FILES) $(ALL_GEN_H_FILES)

$(ALL_LD_FILES):| $(ALL_COMPILED_C_FILES)

$(ALL_EXE_FILES):| $(ALL_LD_FILES)

$(ALL_TEST_FILES):| $(ALL_LD_FILES)

The above creates what can be called a build-phase based DAG, or perhaps an OOD-DAG.  Note that the above cannot build incrementally since the above is not a 'time of creation' DAG - it is only a 'file existence DAG' - it only works when ALL derived (non source) files do not yet exist.
However, if the toolchains and/or build scripts/wrappers (for example, a strace wrapper that smartly records all the file opens of a build step) generate all the fine-grain DAG edges, then on the NEXT incremental build, those edges can be used for an accurate incremental build.
The goal is to remove the fine-grain dependency management 'developer tax' while still being able to build from scratch as well as incrementally.  One can still add DAG tests to the CI/CD pipeline to flag when 'bad' edges are added or add portals/commands that associate a git commit with each DAG edge (a DAG blame command similar to the 'git blame' command) whether the fine-grain edges are manually or automatically generated.
Thanks in advance for any comments or corrections, small or large - appreciate it :-)
p.s. I tried searching in the bazel google group email list and googling around but could not find much.  I am hoping to find a positive answer.  If the answer is negative, it would be great to get confirmation that the idea of a OOD-DAG based bazel build both would work and be a boon for the bazel projects.
